# Error when using biblatex with ACM-reference-format

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography, biblatex

I am using the ACM-Reference-Format. I need to sort the reference based on the order they appear in the paper, so I tried to use `biblatex` package like below:

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
```

But then I got the following error:

[image]

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default the acm classes turn on `natbib` which is not comptabile with `biblatex`.  Fortunately there is an option to turn this off.  You can then use `biblatex` as follows, including your `sorting=none` option:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,natbib=false]{acmart}

\usepackage[style=ACM-Reference-Format,backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample-bibliography.bib}
```

and put

```
\printbibliography
```

at the point in the document when you want the document printed.

Doing this to `sample-sigconf.tex` and adding a `\nocite{*}` results in a bibliography starting as follows, with Lamport as the first reference instead of articles with authors beginning with A.

[image: Sample output]

Here is a minimal document demonstrating this:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,natbib=false]{acmart}

\usepackage[style=ACM-Reference-Format,backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample-bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\title{Contribution title}
\author{A. N. Author}
\maketitle

\textcite{Kosiur01} and \textcite{Cohen07}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

where `sample-bibliography.bib` contains

```
@Article{Cohen07,
  author        = "Sarah Cohen and Werner Nutt and Yehoshua Sagic",
  title         = "Deciding equivalances among conjunctive aggregate queries",
  journal       = JACM,
  articleno     = "5",
  numpages      = "50",
  volume        = "54",
  number        = "2",
  month         = apr,
  year          = "2007",
  doi           = "10.1145/1219092.1219093",
  url           = "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1219092.1219093",
  acmid         = "1219093",
  note          = "",
}

@Book{Kosiur01,
  author =       "David Kosiur",
  title =        "Understanding Policy-Based Networking",
  publisher =    "Wiley",
  year =         "2001",
  address =      "New York, NY",
  edition =      "2nd.",
  editor =       "",
  volume =       "",
  number =       "",
  series =       "",
  month =        "",
  note =         "",
}
```

giving after `pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex`:

[image: Sample output]

Removing the `sorting=none` option results in the opposite order in the bibliography.

Switching to the default backend `biber` instead of `bibtex` will give you access to more features of `biblatex`.

Comment: I tried the above, but keep getting ACM-Reference-Format not found error ...saying l.13046 \RequireBibligographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}  and I do have my ACM-Reference-Format.bst in the folder. Is this approaching conflicting with this bst? or did I miss anything?

Comment: I have this: \documentclass[sigplan,10pt,review, natbib=false]{acmart}\settopmatter{printccs=false,printacmref=false,printfolios=true}

Comment: The files you need are `ACM-Reference-Format.bbx`, `ACM-Reference-Format.cbx` and `ACM-Reference-Format.dbx`.  They are all part of the standard acm distribution.  The `.bst` file is for standard bibtex; biblatex uses these other files.

Comment: added those files. Then I got new errors: File ended while scanning use of \@writefil <inserted text>    \par  l.80 \begin{document} ?   Any ideas?

Comment: You may need to clean out any temporary files you have lying around first.  Otherwise we need to see more code to help debug.  I'll add a minimal document to my answer so you can see what works.

Comment: worked after clean the temp file (copy *.tex to a new file). Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndrewSwann where can I download these files?

Comment: @HendyIrawan The standard site is https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions

Comment: Are the lower-case r and f in the answer typos? The discussion above and my experience (TexLive, Linux) indicates that they must be upper-case?

Comment: @golvok The code works originally as posted - the case seems to be irrelevant.  However, I will update to match the file names in the latest version.

Comment: I guess filesystem case-sensitivity is behind this, then. MacOS and Windows usually don't have case-sensitive file names. Can confirm that file on my system has a title-case name.

Comment: @golvok That sounds like a correct analysis.  The edited version should now work regardless of OS.

Comment: [Since March 2022](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/pull/462), it seems we should use `style=acmnemeric` or `style=acmauthoryear`.